# MinGW completely bugged on NetBeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, compiler-construction, cygwin, mingw

The following code shoudn't produce an error:

```
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <cstdio>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std ;

    int main ( int argc , char** argv )
    {
        int n ;
        cin >> n ;
        cout << n ;
        return 0 ;
    }
```

Yet a get a "RUN FAILED (exit value -1,073,741,511, total time: 46ms)" whilst running MinGW/Msys on Netbeans. Any advice like switching back to Cygwin?

Comment: It's probably something with with shared libraries/run configuration. Can you run the program manually?

Comment: please detail "run the program manually"

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code at all, so the issue is probably your MinGW installation. Try reinstalling it (and/or Netbeans).

Comment: I did that already. Before installing MinGW I was using Cygwin. Then i completely uninstalled Cygwin, installed MinGW and it didn't work. Then I re-installed it and got back to the same place. I was following the instructions on the Netbeans site, for both compilers

Comment: Can you run the executable of your crashing program manually?

Comment: @Ivarpoiss No. I got the following error window: "the procedure entry point __gx_personality_v0 coud not be located in the dynamic library libstdc++-6.dll"

Comment: Either add MinGW/bin to your PATH or set up the run configuration in NetBeans so it could find the dlls. Later option is better because that won't pollute your PATH.

Comment: Been there, done that. Still no success. Switching back to Cygwin

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [MinGW Distro](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html) if you want to develop C++ under a Microsoft Windows operating system. It ships with a pretty new GCC version and with the [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) libraries.

NetBeans IDE is pretty picky regarding the build environment settings. E.g. It doesn't work together with all versions of `make` (we have to distinct `make.exe` from [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) and `mingw32-make.exe` from MinGW for example) and there are [problems regarding the used Java Runtime Enviroment (JRE)](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=228730).

With the settings shown in the following screenshot you should be able to build your example with MinGW Distro and NetBeans 8. I recommend to **not** configure a absolute path to the `make.exe` file but add that path to your Microsoft Windows environment variable `PATH`. Otherwise you may get build errors.

[image: MinGW Build Tools Settings in NetBeans IDE 8.0]

Maybe these two blog posts help if you want to use the "default" MinGW distribution:

1. [Installing Minimum GNU for Windows (MinGW)](http://blog.florianwolters.de/educational/2013/11/21/Installing-MinGW/)
2. [Configure NetBeans IDE for Minimum GNU for Windows (MinGW)](http://blog.florianwolters.de/educational/2013/12/19/Configure_NetBeans_IDE_for_MinGW/)

I hope this helps others as well.

---

Not related to your question: [Don't use `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice):

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int n;
  std::cin >> n;
  std::cout << n;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue (with exit code -1,073,741,511), so though a dated question, I'm posting this here for anyone else who runs into the problem.

1. Run the executable for the program manually. You might get an error such as "the procedure entry point __gx_personality_v0 coud not be located in the dynamic library libstdc++-6.dll". (OP has confirmed this in a comment.)
2. The .dll file referred to in the error message above is either not being linked, or linked incorrectly. The correct version of the .dll that needs to be linked is the one in the ...\MinGW\bin directory. In Windows, you can check the .dll file being linked by typing `where libstdc++-6.dll` in a command prompt;  the first result that is listed will be the file that is linked. If you already see ...\MinGW\bin\libstdc++-6.dll as the first result here, my fix below will not help you.
3. If you see a message "INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).", then ...\MinGW\bin needs to be added to your %PATH% variable. (OP has already confirmed this was not the issue.)
4. The issue I was having was that a program I had installed had its own (likely outdated) version of `libstdc++-6.dll`, which was in a folder also included in my %PATH% variable, ahead of ...\MinGW\bin. This meant that this other .dll file was being picked up and linked to during execution. This can be fixed by editing your %PATH% variable to make sure the ...\MinGW\bin entry is ahead of all other directories that also have a version of the .dll file.

Edit: The other option is to statically link the .dll at program compilation, or place a copy of the correct .dll in the program executable directory. However, neither of these fixes is 'global', and needs to be done for each project individually.

Hope this helps!